# Would 'ruddy' described mean ruddy complexion being a Shepherd or because of genetic make up?

Tags: david

> 12 So he sent and brought him in. Now he was ruddy, with beautiful
> eyes and a handsome appearance. And the LORD said, “Arise, anoint him;
> for this is he.” — 1 Samuel 16:12

All indications would be that he was in top-flight condition having wrestled a bear and (I think) a lion, living in the wild tending his sheep so would it be accurate to tie the word ruddy to a look of high athletic fitness?

P.S. first question. 6th grade graduate with honors I might add and older than you by maybe2x. I have no problem you correcting my grammar. I can take a fair amount of abuse as long as in the end I get accurate correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 1 Sam 16:12, we have a description of the young David that consists of three parts:

- "ruddy", (this word occurs only elsewhere in Gen 25:25, as of Esau, and in 1 Sam 17:42, of David again.)
- "bright eyes"
- "handsome/good looking"

There is no justification for arbitrarily selecting any of these three characteristics as attributable to race or genetics - they are all simply a statement of a young man in the flush of youth and health.

Matthew Poole suggests this:

> **He was ruddy**; which may be referred either to the colour of his hair; or rather, to the complexion of his face.